# StopIteration is being raised and I can't understand why (using next method)

Tags: python, loops, stopiteration

I want my code to understand a **`string`** as a `math expression`, then output me this **`string`** with proper whitespaces.

1. At first, I created my **variables**.

```
operators = ("+", "-", "*", "/", "%", "**", "//") # Math operators the code is going to identify in the string

oper = "20 *25" # The operation string before being formatted ('oper' stands for 'operation')
new_oper = "" # This is going to be the new operation string (desired output)

it = iter(oper.replace(" ", "")) # Removed all whitespaces from the operation string and made it an iterable
```

2. I used the `next()` method once, just so he could understand this method (inside my loop) as the character that comes right after the character the loop is in.

```
next(it)
```

3. Then I started my loop to check every single character in the `operation string` (already with no whitespaces).

```
for x in oper.replace(" ", ""):
    try: # This try checks if I'm able to use the next() method. If I'm not, x is the last character in the string.
        if x not in operators: # x is a number
            if next(it) in operators:
                new_oper += f"{x} " # If an operator comes right after a number, this number is printed with a whitespace, so they don't stay next to each other.
            else:
                new_oper += x   
        elif x in operators: # x is an operator
            if x == "*":
                if next(it) == "*":
                    new_oper += x # If another '*' comes after this '*', then it's a ** operator, so no whitespaces inserted (otherwise, they would be separated)
                else:
                    new_oper += f"{x} "
            elif x == "/":
                if next(it) == "/":
                    new_oper += x # Same here: if there are 2 '/' next to each other, it's another operator ('//'), so no whitespaces inserted
                else:
                    new_oper += f"{x} "
            else:
                new_oper += f"{x} "
    except RuntimeError:
        new_oper += x # x is the last character in the string, no needs to be formatted (it can't be an operator)
```

4. Finally, after formatting everything, I wanted him to print the new string (`new_oper`).

```
print(new_oper)
```

Check out these **outputs** (different values for `oper`):

When

```
oper = "20 *2"
```

Output

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "filename", line 12, in <module>
    if next(it) in operators:
       ^^^^^^^^
StopIteration

# Desired output: 20 * 2
```

---

When

```
oper = "20 +2"
```

Output

```
20 + 2 # Correct output (just changed the operator comparing to the last one)
```

---

When

```
oper = "10+ 3 *2"
```

Output

```
10 + 3*2
# Desired output: 10 + 3 * 2
```

---

I'd appreciate any approach for my problem. I'm not a python expert (far away from that), so I also would appreciate any suggestions or even fixes in my code that may not directly help my problem.

Comment: The `next()` function raises the `StopIteration` exception when it reaches the end of the string and there are no more values to yield.

Comment: But `StopIteration` is not a subclass of `RuntimeError` so is not caught by the `except`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment! I can't believe it was that simple.

Comment: Rather than trying to keep the loop variable `x` and the iterator `it` in sync (so that `next(it)` is *"the character that comes right after the character the loop is in"*), you could use `itertools.pairwise`, which yields pairs of adjacent characters from the string: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.pairwise

Comment: Just as a matter of interest, do you need this to work for floating point numbers?

Comment: Yes, I need to. I just tested using float numbers and it worked perfectly, thanks for reminding me that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you need to change the `except RuntimeError:` to `except StopIteration:` so that it is able to catch the `StopIteration` exception that is thrown by the `next()` when it reaches the end of the string.

You need to change the `else` to make it like this:

```py
else:
    new_oper += f"{x} "
    next(it)
```

Here, the `next(it)` is so that the iterator is always in line with the value of `x`. You call `next(it)` once on all other path of the `if` except this one.

With these 2 changes, it works on the examples given.

---

##### Suggestion:

It might be easier to iterate over the string using [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) like this:

```py
oper2 = oper.replace(" ", "")
for index, x in enumerate(oper2):
```

instead of trying to keep the iterator and the loop in sync. This way, you can refer to the next character as `oper2[index+1]` (`index` is the index of the current character) and for the current character, you can use `x`.
For example, instead of `next(it)`, you would write `oper2[index+1]`. This has the added benefit of being able to look further ahead (but you would need to do `except IndexError:` instead of `except StopIteration:`)

Comment: TRUE! There was a situation in my loop that wasn't calling the next() method. Thank you so much, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

When the iterator that *next()* is working with is exhausted, a StopIteration exception is raised. This can be explicitly caught. e.g.,

```
except StopIteration:
```

Having said that, your implementation is unnecessarily complicated. Consider this:

```
operators = set('+-*/%')
separators = set(',.')

s = '20 //2*43-1** 6+32.5/ 3'

output = []

for c in s.replace(' ', ''):
    if c.isdigit() or c in separators:
        if output and output[-1] in operators:
            output.append(' ')
    else:
        if output and not output[-1] in operators:
            output.append(' ')
    output.append(c)

print(''.join(output))
```

**Output:**

```
20 // 2 * 43 - 1 ** 6 + 32.5 / 3
```